# What is advantage of Logarithmic Sampling?

Tags: filters, audio, sampling, speech-processing, filter-bank

[Logarithmic Fourier Transformation](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2299/813ced58b7bb0daa7e8a9ad549a505194fcd.pdf)

This paper starts off in the abstract saying that the given audio signal is sampled logarithmically. We also know that the human ear has a sort of a filter bank where the filters with centre frequencies less than 1 kHz are spaced linearly whereas the filters greater than 1 kHz are spaced logarithmically. 
Is there any relation between this fact and the reason why the given audio signal in this paper is sampled logarithmically? If there is no relation between the two, can anyone suggest some signal processing literature which uses the above fact known about the human ear?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1120422/125507